# Neo4j query unweighted outdegrees between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I managed to get the outdegrees using:

```
MATCH (n:Artist)-[r:SingsGenre]->(m:Genre)
RETURN n.name as Node, count(r) as outdeg ORDER BY outdeg descending
```

but I would like to ignore the weight in doing so. Is it possible?

Comment: Ignore what weight?

Comment: SingsGenre has a property called weight and that weight is being counted

Comment: Your query is not using that `weight` property at all. It is just counting the number of `SingsGenre` relationships per artist name.